# App crashing in iPad simulator with no useful console info

Tags: xcode, ios, gdb, debugging, stack-trace

please forgive the total newbie here - I am running an app in the simulator, and sometimes when it crashes it posts useful info in the console, other times absolutely nothing. When it posts nothing, what would be good steps to follow to start tracking down the cause of the crash?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all open the debugger after the crash and look at the stacktrace.

In addition to that you could enable [NSZombieEnabled](http://cocoa-nut.de/?p=16) for the executable when those vague bad access errors show up.

**Debugger with stacktrace(top left window), XCode3**

[image]

**Stacktrace Xcode4**

[image]

Comment: NSZombieEnabled is great.  It can really save you on some of these random inexplicable crashes.

Answer (score 5):

I can continuously reproduce this kind of behavior with our app. It uses ARC so im pretty sure nothing gets over released, and we have zombies enabled. Xcode will say "Paused" instead of displaying a list of threads, the "Continue" button is active, but doesn't do anything, and entering **bt** on the (gdb) prompt says **No stack.**

This is driving me crazy!

Answer (score 0):

Determine on what event the app is crashing. For exapmple if the app is crashing on the click of a UIButton, you can put a breakpoint on the action and step through code lines to see on which line the crash happens. Sometimes when there is no crash log on the crash of app, debugging through this method, does prove to be helpful.

I suppose this is a memory issue.

Comment: I'm sure its a memory/threading issue, but we have way too much code to put in break points. Is there **any** other way please?

Comment: @Maciej Swic: Same problem with me pal. My app crashes after some 5 lines of memory warning logs with level 1 and 2 :( Any other way please?

Answer (score 0):

sometimes it happens to me as well.. the app crashes without any error message getting posted in the logs.. 95% of the time it is because I would be not be releasing something or would be releasing something and accessing it( which would usually create a log)... go through your code and see whether you are releasing properly and using autorelease option where needed...